# How do I use htaccess to show the first /directory/ name to be at the beginning of the url like a subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How would I move the first folder in a url to be at the beginning of a url with htaccess.

From this:  www.example.com/folder/index.php
To this:  folder.example.com

And also make so if I want to go to folder.example.com/orders, it doesn't do this folder.example.com/folder/orders

I'm not real familiar with writing htaccess rewrite rules, but was trying to put this together from stuff I read:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on   
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^%{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm looking to use it for a web application to direct each user to their own folder.  Any help or thoughts if this would be a good practice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with htaccess without properly configuring your domain name.

Comment: It is not possible throught .htaccess. You need to do it through your cpanel by creating sub-domain and pointing it to particular folder